# Plotting dot function using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the problem following : Let's say that we have three variables and we want to make a plot, so

```
df <- data.frame(x=rep(1:5, 3), val=sample(1:100, 15), 
                 variable=rep(paste0("category", 1:3), each=5))
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=x,y=val))+geom_line(aes(colour=variable))
```

[image]

And now I want identical image as above but where graphs are dots not lines. I'm not sure how can I do it, I read about geom_dots but I didn't get the point.

Comment: Do you want `ggplot(data=df,aes(x=x,y=val,color=variable))+geom_point()`?

Comment: No we're talking! Thanks mate!